# When I am using facebook page plugin widget , got an error

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, widget

When  I am using facebook page plugin widget , got an error in the console. Only this error displaying when I use Tabs value timeline.

Note:
I am using wordpress, using page builder plugin.

**Console Error**

```
ErrorUtils caught an error: "<![EX[["Tried to listen to element of type %s from %s: %s","click","Error","C...". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
```

**Facebook Plugin**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin